# How to avoid method overwritten warnings with precompilation?

Tags: julia, precompile

I'm trying to precompile my package to reduce startup time, and I've the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116045/why-is-julia-taking-a-long-time-on-the-first-call-into-my-module) and the manual to get some information. I added some precompile hints (as in the SO answer) and now I see a ton of warnings when using my module. I was able to recreate these warnings with a new package called `PrecompileTester` which has the contents:

```
__precompile__()
module PrecompileTester
module M
    using SpecialFunctions
    const A = digamma(1) # precompile hint
    const B = digamma(1.0) # precompile hint
end
end # module
```

The warnings all seem to say that I'm overwriting a function at X with the same function from the same place. Here are the last two lines of the warning output:

```
...

WARNING: Method definition digamma(Union{Float16, Main.Base.Complex{Float16}, Float32, Main.Base.Complex{Float32}}) in module SpecialFunctions at /Users/user/.julia/v0.6/SpecialFunctions/src/gamma.jl:497 overwritten in module SpecialFunctions at /Users/user/.julia/v0.6/SpecialFunctions/src/gamma.jl:497.
WARNING: Method definition digamma(Number) in module SpecialFunctions at /Users/user/.julia/v0.6/SpecialFunctions/src/gamma.jl:501 overwritten in module SpecialFunctions at /Users/user/.julia/v0.6/SpecialFunctions/src/gamma.jl:501.
```

What is going on here, and how do I precompile without all these warnings?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce, How did you create the package, or is it just that file? Try to create a package for this: `Pkg.add("PkgDev"); using PkgDev; PkgDev.generate("PrecompileTester", "MIT")`, then add your example to `PrecompileTester/src/PrecompileTester.jl` and finally test with `using PrecompileTester`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce! You described exactly what I did, and you can see the results in the linked screenshot of my IDE. https://imgur.com/a/5ylHV Here is my versioninfo, can you post yours? Julia Version 0.6.0
Commit 903644385b (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)

Comment: My version is: `v"0.6.3-pre.0"`

Comment: Oddly I can no longer reproduce this.