# Julia DifferentialEquations package SLOW and HEAVY?

Tags: julia

I am very new to Julia with python background and I am just testing `DifferentialEquations` package.
I run a simple `jl` script from command line and the problem is that it takes about a minute to run a simple code that Benchmark shows it need a few milliseconds to execute and also it take about 1GB of RAM. Am I doing something wrong or it is quite normal in Julia?

This is the simple script I got from the Tutorial:

```
import DifferentialEquations
import Plots

pl = Plots
df = DifferentialEquations

f(u,p,t) = 0.98u
u0 = 1.0
tspan = (0.0, 1.0)
prob = df.ODEProblem(f, u0, tspan)
sol = df.solve(prob)
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Julia 1.4.

Comment: Firstly, Plots takes a long time compile, and you don't seem to be using it, so try removing it from the script. Secondly, you should run Julia scripts from the Julia REPL. Running it from the command line will be slow every time, it's just not the right workflow for Julia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you're seeing is mainly compilation time = Julia compiles native code for any method upon its first invocation, so yes it's normal to see longer runtimes and higher memory usage on the first run. The times reported in benchmarks are usually obtained using the `BenchmarkTools` package which will run a function multiple times to give a more accurate picture of its actual runtime, discarding the compilation time (similar to Python's `%timeit` functionality).

Comment: What do you mean by the first time? If I run the script again It also take the same time to execute. It is very disappointing to run a bunch of scripts from bash script.

Comment: By the first time I mean the first time in a Julia session - if you close the session and restart it your methods will have to compile again. There's already a similar question with a lot of detailed answers here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116045/why-is-julia-taking-a-long-time-on-the-first-call-into-my-module

Comment: It is good to note that for such small exercises, the typical workflow in julia is having a long-running session. The workflow of having scripts with one small function that is called only once, and calling it from the terminal, is not well suited for julia due to the compilation. I have seen that many python users struggle with this because they bring their old workflow exactly the same.

Comment: @ARamirez and Nils Gudat  May be this should be mentioned in the early steps tutorial, it there is not (I did not find), it is kind of confusing for newcomers.